# Reverse for 'Newsdetail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:Django error

Tags: django

In the following links direct to same URL name with different params,

```
 <div onclick="location.href='{% url 'newscountry' 'Saudi' %}'">
      x
    </div>
    <div "onclick="location.href='{% url 'newscountry' 'UAE' %}'">
      y
    </div>
```

However when the second div element is clicked it gives an error, but the first link works fine.

URL.PY

```
   path('country/<str:countryname>/',NewsCountryView.as_view(),name='newscountry'),
```

VIEW.PY

```
class NewsCountryView(ListView):
    model = News
    template_name = 'newsfront/index.html' # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'news'
    
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        country=self.kwargs.get('countryname')
        return News.objects.filter(country=country)
```

Full trace back

```
NoReverseMatch at /country/UAE/
Reverse for 'Newsdetail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['news/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\Z']


Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'Newsdetail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['news/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\Z']
```

Comment: Share the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the database, one of the resultant page had broken URL.I mean one of the modal instance was missing url